# BY-SA 4.0 Bulk Compatible Other Licenses likes MIT, BSD3

Tags: mit, license-compatibility, bsd, cc-by-sa

On the CCL official website, it says BY-SA 4.0 is compatible with FAL and GPL 3.0 (one-way only).

Then, is it compatible with other licenses such as MIT and BSD licenses? Other license -> BY-SA 4.0 direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MIT license is probably compatible with CC-BY-SA, but only in one way (MIT->CC-BY-SA).

BSD 2 and 3 clauses also should be compatible.

BSD 4 clause may be compatible, but compatibility, in this case, is complicated. But... nobody uses BSD4.

MIT and BSD licenses are permissive licenses with the following conditions:

- place all copyright notices
- place license text
- (for X11 MIT version and BSD 3 clause) don't use my name for promoting a product without my permission

CC-BY-SA says:

- Place all copyright notices
- Place license text OR URL to license text
- Don't use my name in Your use of work.
- Copyleft

CC-BY-SA allows to use of external work because You must provide copyright notices, so just place MIT/BSD license text with work.

The most controversial thing is "Don't use my name without my permission".

Just look out for licenses:

MIT:
MIT license(Expat version, the most popular) does not include this clause, but the X11 version says:

> Except as contained in this notice,
> the name(s) of the above copyright holders
> shall not be used in advertising or otherwise
> to promote the sale, use, or other dealings in
> this Software without prior written authorization.

BSD 3-clause:

> 3. Neither the name of the copyright holder nor the names of its contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived from this software without specific prior written permission.

CC-BY-SA (human-readable summary)

> Attribution — You must give appropriate credit, provide a link to the license, and indicate if changes were made. You may do so in any reasonable manner, **but not in any way that suggests the licensor endorses you or your use.**

So, merging projects licensed under MIT or BSD licenses with CC-BY-SA 4.0 should be legal, and the result is CC-BY-SA 4.0 licensed.

Remember to include all copyright notices and texts of licenses. I recommend placing also CC-BY-SA 4.0 license text. You can get it in text format from the CC website: https://creativecommons.org/2014/01/07/plaintext-versions-of-creative-commons-4-0-licenses/

Just download CC-BY-SA 4.0 legal code and place it into your project.

**Note: this answer is not legal advice! I'm not a lawyer.**